# R Shiny SelectizeInput dropdown avoid auto close

Tags: r, shiny

How to prevent the selectizeInput/pickerInput dropdown from closing by clicking outside in R Shiny?. Here is the sample code to explain the problem. I need to always see the selectizeInput choices even the user clicks the shiny body somewhere. The main selectizeInput dropdown should not close.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  div(HTML("<br><br><br>")),
  
  selectizeInput(
    'upwardId', label = "Select Number", choices = 1:40, 
    options = list(maxItems = 20)
  ),
  
  div(HTML("<br><br><br>")),
  
  pickerInput(
        inputId = "month",
        label = "Select a month",
        choices = c("Jan","Feb","March","Apr","May"),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = pickerOptions(
          maxOptions=3,
          dropupAuto = FALSE,
          actionsBox = TRUE,
          title = "Please select a month",
          header = "title..."
        
      ))
  
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session){}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: In that case, perhaps `checkboxgroupinput()` or `radiogroupbuttons()` might be more appropriate.